# zsh: replace custom text with a hyperlink

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I have a command that outputs a lot of text that has some numbers within the output, specifically 20-digit numbers. These 20-digit numbers are identifiers to a specific web resource (like `https://example.com?q={20-digit-number}`.

How do I customize stdout to replace any 20-digit number with a clickable URL on iterm2 + zsh?

I've looked into creating my own `oh-my-zsh` plugin, but I can't seem to find a way to hook into the printed output

Comment: You could pipe the stdout of your script to `sed`, for generating the URL. To make it clickable, go to the iTerm2 preferences, the _pointer_ tab. There is a checkbox for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

On iTerm2 the functionality to click on Hyperlinks using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd> + click** should be already included.

If instead you want to output your 20-digit-number links with a different format, I suggest you read this page on [Hyperlinks in terminal emulators](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda), especially the [Quick Example](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda#quick-example).

You can also think about creating [Triggers](https://iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html) with the **Make Hyperlink** action whenever the text in the terminal matches one of the 20-digit-links.